# Long press gesture get called twice when Alert view is shown

Tags: objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I'm having some troubles with long press gesture here. I've look around and found some post related to my issues, but no luck until now.

I have a long press gesture for a view, and I want to show an alert view when the gesture is trigger, but somehow the trigger got called twice when the alert view is shown, I've check the state of the gesture recognizer but still no luck. Here the code:

Initial code:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longTap = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];

[longTap setMinimumPressDuration:1];
[self addGestureRecognizer:longTap];


- (IBAction)handleTapGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender {
if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
NSLog(@"Change");
} else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
NSLog(@"Ended");
}
else {
NSLog(@"Begin");
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Long pressed" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show]; //If I remove this line, the trigger is call only once. 
}
}
```

The wierd thing is, if I remove the [alert show], everything goes as expected, the gesture is trigger only once. 
Anyone has the explanation for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you missing any gesture states?

Comment: there aresome other states, but as I mentioned, this problem only happens with when I put [alert show] message, and the states of the gesture when it's triggered are both UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan

Comment: But if you want to show the alert view when your long press gesture is triggered, you should simply show it in its selector. Why are you trying to capture a long press gesture's various states for showing an alert?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use below code for your solution.

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longTap = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
[longTap setMinimumPressDuration:1];
longTap.delegate = (id)self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:longTap];


- (void)handleTapGesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        NSLog(@"Change");
    }
    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        NSLog(@"Ended");
    }
    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        NSLog(@"Begin");
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Long pressed" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show]; //If I remove this line, the trigger is call only once.
    }
}
```

Comment: @hoangCap try again. The Nilay answer is correct. You long press (if you press enough) will star with UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan, and I will stop with UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded or UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled.

Comment: Yeah it works, thanks Nilay Shah.
Actually the last trigger was caused by UIGestureRecognizerStateCancel, not UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan.